# File not found with VirtualHost and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-vhost-alias

I'm bulding a RESTful api based on [Tonic](http://peej.github.com/tonic/).
On my developer machine and our stage server we use virtual hosts.

Tonic uses a .htaccess file to translate the incomming calls to it's dispatcher.php file. This works fine on servers without VirtualHosts enabled.

However if i enable VirtualHosts i get a file not found even thought the path and name to the file is correct.

Here is the VirtualHost setup on my developer machine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@xxxxxxxxxxxx
    ServerAlias *.dev.xxxxx
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/xxxxxxxx/workspace/%1
    <Directory /home/xxxxxxxx/workspace/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And Tonic's .htacces located in a folder called rest in the project root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch\.php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* dispatch.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

A call to http://project.dev.xxxxx/rest/ gives:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /home/xxxxxxxx/workspace/project/rest/dispatch.php was 
not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxxxxx Port 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you're misusing `VirtualDocumentRoot`.  Try changing it to:

`DocumentRoot /home/xxxxxxxx/workspace/project/rest`

Also, here's a good explanation on the `VirtualDynamicRoot`: [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html)

Hope that helps.